# Inserting article:tags meta in html head-element, using get tags, no wp_head

Tags: page-template, wp-head, tags

I´m trying to add code to a template file of mine, working with a raw theme I generated from “”. The file is a duplicate of single.php and called single-post.php. Like WP states in Codex. I am trying to add my tags of my post to the  of my pages for blog posts. I want to wrap them in code for META tags, namely the article:tags. Whatever I do I keep getting the correct output, but no actual information, no tag names.

I am not using the wp_head in the template file. For custom reasons. Also, I have been trying without and with the loop present before my calls to the get_tags. Additionally, this is made with code that is not usable in `head`, I know, but it doesn´t matters, this happens no matter what I put there. Will have the `meta` tags later.

Basic WP code (supposedly for single posts):
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags

```
<?php

  $tags = get_tags();
  $html = '<div class="post_tags">';
  foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
    $tag_link = get_tag_link( $tags->term_id );

    $html .= "<a href='{$tag_link}' title='{$tags->name} Tag' class='{$tags->slug}'>";
    $html .= "{$tags->name}</a>";
  }
  $html .= '</div>';
  echo $html;

?>
```

Adding this code produces:

Now I´ve tried this with some small mods, using the post while loop:

```
<?php

if( have_posts() ):

        while( have_posts() ): the_post();

        // here´s the tag code
        $tags = get_tags();
        $html = '<div class="post_tags">';
        foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
            $tag_link = get_tag_link( $tags->term_id );

            $html .= "<a href='DELETE' title='{$tags->name} Tag' class='DELETE'>";
            $html .= "{$tags->name}</a>";
        }
        $html .= '</div>';
        echo $html;

    ?>

<?php endwhile;

endif;

?>
```

It still produces:

```
<div class="post_tags">
    <a href='DELETE' title=' Tag' class='DELETE'></a>
    <a href='DELETE' title=' Tag' class='DELETE'></a>
    <a href='DELETE' title=' Tag' class='DELETE'></a>
    <a href='DELETE' title=' Tag' class='DELETE'></a>
</div>
```

The title tag is still empty, `title=' Tag'`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after some more tinkering, I found another solution. This one works with or *without the **loop***. So adding it in the template file or your **single.php** is fine, in the `<head>` of the HTML.

```
<?php $tags = get_the_tags($post->ID);  ?>
<?php foreach($tags as $tag) :  ?>
    <meta property="article:tag" content="<?php print_r($tag->name);?>" />
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

It also works on the page, I get it working **with no html or php present** whatsoever in the single.php.